# Facing Issue on gRPC service in my project

Tags: jmeter, grpc

I'm getting the below error to execute my gRPC request in Jmeter. Please help me sort out this issue and what I'm missing in the script.

```
ERROR v.z.b.GRPCSampler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Caught exception while parsing request for rpc
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.ClientCaller.buildRequestAndMetadata(ClientCaller.java:187)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.initGrpcInCurrentThread(GRPCSampler.java:204)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.initGrpcRequestSampler(GRPCSampler.java:133)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.sample(GRPCSampler.java:90)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:630)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Thanks,
Siva Ganesh

I'm expecting the right solution to this issue.

Comment: and where is your script?